# unity3d: how to swap between 2 navmesh at run time?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created 2 navMesh in my 3D scene:
- 1 big rectangle called "navBig"
- 1 small circle INSIDE that big rectangle called "navCircle"

I want to swap between these 2 navmeshes at runtime: sometimes player can only move inside the circle (that is inside the big rectangle) , sometimes he can move in the whole rectangle

I tried:

```
void Start() {
        navCircle = GameObject.Find("navCircle");
        navBig = GameObject.Find("navBig");
        navBig.SetActive(false);
        navCircle.SetActive(true); // this should enable movement inside the circle only
}
```

But it has no effect : any idea ?

Comment: Unity's builtin NavMesh system is not designed to handle this sort of thing (along with other typically desired use-cases).

Comment: There is a multi navmesh option on unity github.  You can probably use that and swap option at runtime